# "meta" and "parent" navigation links in header missing

Tags: bug, status-completed

Main site:

[image]

On meta:

[image]

Update: also on the meta bar the *chat* link sends me to http://chat.meta.askubuntu.com/ which does not work

Comment: This appears to be related to [Why AskUbuntu has disappeared from the StackExchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73405/why-askubuntu-has-disappeared-from-the-stackexchange-sites) as well as the [Onebox has stopped working on Ask Ubuntu chat.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73408/onebox-has-stopped-working-on-ask-ubuntu-chat)

Comment: @Marco This appears to be now be fixed, you can mark it as such if you like?

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed. It was due to [a bad setting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73411/163868) made by the devs.